# Wildfly Eclipselink checkForUnregisteredExistingObject NullPointerException

Tags: java, null, eclipselink, wildfly

I have a problem that I can't save a simple object to database. The project was originally using Hibernate but I changed to Eclipselink.

I have others project with Eclipselink but not with this configuration and this server (Wildfly 10.x).

I'm not sure if can be a conflict with some JBOSS libs.

This is the error:

```
20:54:34,322 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-12) javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException    
2018-05-09 20:54:34 ERROR [context:222] javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException    
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:773)
```

My POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools</groupId>
<artifactId>portal</artifactId>
<version>${warVersion}</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <warVersion>0.0.1</warVersion>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom.eap>7.1.1.GA</version.jboss.bom.eap>

    <!-- other plug-in versions -->
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE APIs including a Bill
    of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection)
    of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions
    of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools stack (you can read this as
    the JBoss stack of the Java EE APIs, with some extras tools for your project, such
    as Arquillian for testing) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.el/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <!-- ECLIPSELINK -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa -->
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
     -->

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PRIMEFACES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
     -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- FILTER FILE TO REPLACE MAVEN VALUES -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name
        given to the generated WAR, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Surefire plug-in is responsible for running tests
            as part of project build -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plug-in deploys the WAR to a local JBoss EAP container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <!-- 
            <configuration>
                <hostname>CPM-WIN-SVR1</hostname>
                <port>9990</port>
                <username>jenkins</username>
                <password>jenkins-1004</password>
            </configuration>
             -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it
            to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
        <!-- Separate profiles are provided for running all tests, including
            Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
            in your JBoss EAP instance -->
        <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss EAP instance, and execute
            the test, shutting it down when done -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
            in a remote JBoss EAP instance -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- 
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         -->
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PFITools</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>jpa/UserDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/QuestionDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/OptionDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/AssessmentQuestionDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/QuestionTypeDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/AssessmentQuestionAnswerDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/ArtifactDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/CompanyDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/AssessmentCaseDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/AssessmentDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/AssessmentQuestionCommentDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/CaseCheckListDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/ActivityDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/StakeholderDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>jpa/StakeholderContactDAO.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.FactVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ActivityVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ActivityLogVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ArtifactVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ArtifactClassificationVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ArtifactTypeVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentCaseVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentQuestionVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentQuestionAnswerVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentQuestionCommentVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.AssessmentSectionVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.BreachOverviewVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.CaseCheckListVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.CaseStakeholderContactVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.CaseVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.CompanyVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ConfigVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.CountryVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.MilestoneVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.OptionVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.QuestionVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.QuestionTypeVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.StakeholderVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.StakeholderContactVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.StakeholderRequirementVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.StakeholderTypeVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.ThirdPartyVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.UserTypeVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.UserVO</class>
        <class>au.com.chillipepper.pfitools.portal.vo.WorkDiaryVO</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="PostgreSQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

- Wildfly 10.x with Eclipselink 2.5.2 added in modules folder

I tried other newer versions of Eclipselink but is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the stack trace when using the later version exactly the same?  I'd guess this is a class loader issue, where the loader used for the object being merged (I'm just guessing as you didn't show the full stack) isn't the same as the one used to deploy the persistence unit, preventing EclipseLink from finding the mappings for the object passed in.  You might try putting the EL libraries in a different location such as on the server as a shared library, but I'm not familiar with using Wildfly or POMs to make detailed or specific suggestions

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll check that about EL libs. I'll add the full stack trace here for more details.

Comment: How did you install EclipseLink?

Comment: In the application I 'm using POM and but I'm also added in "modules" for Wildfly as recommended. Is that what are you asking about "install"?